# JavaScript custom method

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have created a custom object and added a method to it which is called changeColor with an attribute. The idea is when I attach this method to any DOM element  that elements  all content color must change.

Here is my started code:

```
function CustomColor() {

}

CustomColor.prototype.changeColor = function(color){
   //here what I have to specify.

}
```

This is pretty basic but I am new to JavaScript.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand *"I will attach this method to any DOM element that elements all content color will change"*. Which DOM elements' color do you want to change? Extending the DOM with your own methods is a bad idea, but creating wrappers is no problem.

Comment: Wells thanks, but what is the question.

Comment: Ok, in my web page one paragraph is there. And its id is myParagraph. So when I will attach to the changeColor method to the paragraph, it will change the specified color.

Comment: That would be pretty useless, if you change all the color attributes then most elements will be nothing but a unicoloured block. In any case, changing an attribute is so simple in the first place that making a custom method for it makes little sense, you can't make anything substantially simpler than `element.style.color="red"`.

Comment: Just change the color! It's pointless to attach the suggested custom function/method to another DOM element that changes the colour like this, unless of course you're simply looking at the principals behind it.

Comment: The thing is I am learning in object oriented way. So idea is when I wll call that method, and pass all the variable, element will change based on the variable.

Comment: @nareshkumar Stop trying to learn object oriented programming, you are not going to understand it until you know your imperative programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use CustomColor like this:

```
function CustomColor(element) {
    this.element = element;
}
CustomColor.prototype.changeColor = function (color) {
    this.element.style.color = color;
}
```

new instance of CustomColor:

```
var element = new CustomColor(document.body);
element.changeColor('red');
```

you can also extend the actual dom element without using any extra classes like this:

```
Element.prototype.changeColor = function (color) {
    this.style.color = color;
};
```

and use it like this:

```
document.body.changeColor('red')
```

Comment: Thanks my friend for your help. I applied your logic in my code. It is working just fine.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose this is what you're looking after:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('some_element'),
    CustomColor = function (element) {
        this.htmlElement = element;
    };
CustomColor.prototype.changeColor = function (color) {
    this.htmlElement.style.color = color;
    return;
};
elem.customColor = new CustomColor(elem);
```

Using attached property:

```
elem.customColor.changeColor('#00f');
```

Only way to get a reference to the hosting HTML element is to pass it as an argument to the constructor. However, in `changeColor` you can't refer any "private" variable of `CustomColor` (including its arguments), hence you'll need to create a "public" property for all those properties you want to use in `changeColor`. More info at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

A live demo at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/46P6Q/).

The code above creates a custom property only to a specific HTML element. It's not recommended to create custom properties to the `prototype` of a DOM element, since those are not supported in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the name local inside a function or object.

```
let ob = {
    theif : 'Davron',
    height : 1.7,
    color : {
        hair : 'qora',
        esee : 'white',
    },

    methodName: function () {
        return 'This is medthod';
    }
}

console.log(ob.methodName());
```